# Alternatives to array_agg()?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Is there any alternative to the PostgreSQL `array_agg()` function so that it doesn't return values in the format: *'{x,y,z,}'*.
Can I have it return just: *'x,y,z'* ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In **PostgreSQL 9.0** or later use [**`string_agg(val, ',')`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE).
It returns a string with delimiters of your choosing.

[`array_agg(val)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) returns an *array*, no surprise there. The curly braces you see are integral part of [*array literals*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) - the text representation of arrays.

In older versions (or any version really) you can substitute with `array_to_string(array_agg(val), ',')`.

Or, quick'n'dirty: `trim(array_agg(val)::text, '{}'` - if values never start or end with curly braces.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not on 9.0 yet (which has the already mentioned `string_agg()` function) you can use `array_to_string()` on the result of `array_agg()`

Answer (score 2):

Use the STRING_AGG function:

```
SELECT
  STRING_AGG(name, ',')
FROM
  person;
```