# Aggregate strings in descending order in a PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, postgresql-8.4

In addition to the question [How to concatenate strings of a string field in a PostgreSQL 'group by' query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query)

How can I sort employee in descending order?

I am using PostgreSQL 8.4 which doesn't support `string_agg()`. I've tried to use the following, but it isn't supported:

```
array_to_string(array_agg(employee ORDER BY employee DESC), ',')
```

I'd appreciate any hint to the right answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In PostgreSQL **9.0** or later you can [order elements inside aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

```
SELECT company_id, string_agg(employee, ', ' ORDER BY company_id DESC)::text
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Neither `string_agg()` nor that `ORDER BY` are available for PostgreSQL **8.4**. You have to pre-order values to be aggregated. Use a subselect or [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) (pg 8.4+) for that:

```
SELECT company_id, array_to_string(array_agg(employee), ', ')
FROM  (SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY company_id, employee DESC) x
GROUP  BY 1;
```

I order by `company_id` in addition as that should speed up the subsequent aggregation.

Less elegant, but faster. (Still true for Postgres 14.)

See:

- [Concatenate multiple result rows of one column into one, group by another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847173/concatenate-multiple-result-rows-of-one-column-into-one-group-by-another-column/15850510#15850510)
- [Alternatives to array_agg()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524994/alternatives-to-array-agg/9525081#9525081)